# Less-than sign in python parameter docstring not showing up in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a simple function that I document like this:

```
def fun(x):
    """
    My function

    :param x: 0 <= x <= 1, blah blah
    """
    pass
```

Unfortunately, in PyCharm, if I either hit Ctrl-Q or just hover over the function, the documentation box that pops up is missing the `<` signs.  Instead the box just says `Params -- 0 = x = 1, blah blah`.  Trying to escape the `<` doesn't help.  Anyone know a fix?

On edit: thanks to @Marat, the issue is that PyCharm uses HTML for the `:param` part of the doc string but not for the main body of the doc string.  So this means that to get everything to show up correctly, I would do something like this:

```
def fun(x):
    """
    My function (make sure 0 <= x <= 1)

    :param x: 0 &lt= x &lt= 1, blah blah
    """
    pass
```

But then `help(fun)` will show up wrong, but looks like this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug/feature in PyCharm. Apparently it supports HTML in docstrings, replacement of `<` with `&lt;` fixes the problem.

UPD: HTML is only supported in param/returns/data strings, including Google-style definitions (`Args: ...`). Still not sure if it is a bug or a feature.

Comment: if replace `<` with `&lt` when aply `help(fun)` will not bring the expected result

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is as good an answer as possible. As @JailtonSilva points out, that will break `help(fun)`, but that's how it is. And yes, html is not supported in the main body of the docstring, which means that `0 <= x <= 1` shows up fine as long as it's at the top and not in the `:param` part.  Okay.

Comment: @mrip another "solution" is to put "1 >= x >= 0" hahaha

Comment: lol, yeah.  I thought about something like `x in [0, 1]` to mean the closed real interval `[0,1]` but of course that just looks like a python list consisting of `0` and `1`